# Configuring emma with maven to generate xml or text reports

Tags: maven, emma

I am trying to add emma to project build. I went through the tutorials here - 
[Maven emma plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/emma-maven-plugin/usage.html)

But i am not able to figure out how do I specify what kind of reports to generate - i mean txt or xml. How do I add this part to the maven build so that when the POM file builds it generates either txt or xml report in some specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality has been included in the development version of the Sonatype Emma Plugin, emma-maven-plugin-1.3-SNAPSHOT, but it has not been released yet.

https://github.com/sonatype/emma-maven-plugin/pull/1

and

https://github.com/sonatype/emma-maven-plugin/pull/2

Note that this is not the same as the Codehaus Emma plugin that you referenced in your question, but the change should be minimal.

Once version 1.3 is released, you should be able to put the following in the reporting section of your pom.xml file to get the full range of output formats:

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>html,xml,txt</formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emma4it-maven-plugin for reporting. The 1.3 version has some issue. 
But the 1.4-SNAPSHOT works fine. 
Here is the git link for the same : https://github.com/billmag/emma4it-maven-plugin.git
Clone the repo and do a mvn clean install.

Also you can use 1.2 version in case you don't want to use a SNAPSHOT version.

```
The configuration in pom for reporting is as follows:
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma4it-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                     <verbosity.level>verbose</verbosity.level>
                     <metadatas>coverage.em path</metadatas>
                     <instrumentations>coverage.ec path</instrumentations>
                     <reportDirectory>target/emma/</reportDirectory>
                     <baseDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</baseDirectory>
                     <formats>xml,html</formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </reporting>

Command to get the reports 
mvn org.sonatype.maven.plugin:emma4it-maven-plugin:1.4-SNAPSHOT:report
```